# Does the "on a rail" achievement work in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm just wondering because one block in the Nether means 8 blocks in the Overworld and would make it easier.

I have not tried this yet but I want to know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievements):

> Travel by minecart to a point at least 500 blocks from where the player started. Distance is measured in a straight line.

It doesn't specify what dimension you need to be in so this means you **need** to travel 500 blocks regardless on whether you're in the Overworld or not.